# Change condition to NOT EXISTS

Tags: sql, oracle

Name of Table:Table_1 / Alias = LP
Name of Table:Table_2 / Alias = BA

Earlier condition: [part of a large query]

```
AND LP.P_ID = BA.ID
```

Change: LP.P_ID doesn’t exist for BA.ID.

Tried the below solution:

```
AND NOT EXISTS(select 1 from Table_1 LP1 where LP1.P_ID = BA.ID)
```

Is above condition same as : LP.P_ID != BA.ID ??

Also removal of initial condition and replacing with the one mentioned above is causing a MERGE JOIN (CARTESIAN).

Comment: The two conditions are not equivalent.

Comment: If at all, `AND LP.P_ID = BA.ID` would require an `EXISTS` predicate, not a `NOT EXISTS`